# using dataloader to interface kafka data

Tags: apache-kafka, multiprocessing, pytorch, dataloader

i use dataloader to inferface the data in kafka and it doesnt work

here is my code

```
class kfkdataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self,consumer,image_size):
    super(kfkdataset).__init__()
    self.image_size=image_size
    self.consumer = consumer
def __getitem__(self, index):
    info = json.loads(next(self.consumer).value)
    image_osspath = info['path']
    image = prep_image_batch(image_osspath,self.image_size)
    return image,image_osspath


def __len__(self):
    # You should change 0 to the total size of your dataset.
    return 9000000


consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',bootstrap_servers=[])

prodataset = kfkdataset(consumer,image_size=608)#)
k = DataLoader(prodataset,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_workers=16)
for inputimage,osspath in k:

    inputimage = inputimage.to(device)
    detections,_ = model(inputimage)
detections = non_max_suppression(detections, 0.98, 0.4)
```

it works when num_workers is 1

when num_workers >1:
errors came out

```
File "batch_upload.py", line 80, in <module>
for inputimage,osspath in k:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 801, in__next__
     return self._process_data(data)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 846,in_process_data
     data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
FileExistsError: Caught FileExistsError in DataLoader worker process 1.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/appbatch/utils/utils.py", line 49, in __getitem__
    info = json.loads(next(self.consumer).value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1192, in __next__
    return self.next_v2()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1200, in next_v2
    return next(self._iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1115, in _message_generator_v2
    record_map = self.poll(timeout_ms=timeout_ms, update_offsets=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 654, in poll
    records = self._poll_once(remaining, max_records, update_offsets=update_offsets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 701, in _poll_once
    self._client.poll(timeout_ms=timeout_ms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 600, in poll
    self._poll(timeout / 1000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 629, in _poll
    self._register_send_sockets()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 619, in _register_send_sockets
    self._selector.modify(key.fileobj, events, key.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 261, in modify
    key = self.register(fileobj, events, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 412, in register
    self._epoll.register(key.fd, epoll_events)
  FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

i want know how to make it works

Comment: How many partitions do you have in this kafka topic?

Comment: it seems like  have 12 partitions

Comment: I see.. I think it is a connection socket problem

Answer (score 0):

Basically, setting `num_workers > 1` in PyTorch's DataLoader is creating several worker processes which are in turn biding to the same socket port as there is only one consumer.

One approach to parallelize and improve importing data from Kafka is to create several consumers in the same consumer group for that topic.